# Read the data from the list in the desired format

Tags: c#

can someone help me, I do not know which part I'm missing, and all of the data that I'm reading in "sb" are only one display.

Specifically, I want to get EventToolTipText out all the time from the arrivals

Currently I get only one data from the list type:

> Von: 08:00:00 Bis: 12:00:00,

and I should print all the data types:

> Von: 08:00:00 Bis: 12:00:00, 
>   Von: 12:00:00 Bis: 14:00:00, 
>   Von: 14:00:00 Bis: 18:00:00,

this is my code:

```
CustomEvent cevent = null;
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int n = 0; n < arrivals.Count; n++)
                        {

                            sb.AppendFormat("Von: {0} Bis: {1} \n", arrivals[n].ZPZ_Von.TimeOfDay, arrivals[n].ZPZ_Bis.TimeOfDay);

                            cevent = new Calendar.NET.CustomEvent()
                            {
                                IgnoreTimeComponent = true,
                                Date = arrivalDates[i],
                                EventText = c + new DateTime(1989, 1, 1, workingHours.Hours, workingHours.Minutes, workingHours.Seconds).ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "\n" + error,
                                EventColor = Color.Red,
                                EventToolTipText = sb.ToString()
                                };

                            if (!generatedEvents.Any(x => x.Date == cevent.Date))
                            {
                                calendar1.AddEvent(cevent);
                                generatedEvents.Add(cevent);

                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Have you debugged into the for loop to make sure arrivals.Count is actually 3? Just to check the most simple case, did you try to remove the new line char '\n' and see whether this makes any difference?

Comment: @AirLancer if I tried, the same thing still happens, count is 3, just strange it does not show, String Builder is good, this part of the code is a bit coarse

Comment: When you say the string builder is good, I assume that sb contains three elements at the end. It might help to see the code when you call the sb. Or is the issue with the lists down below where you do 'AddEvent' and 'Add'.

Comment: @AirLancer that you understand me well, and I think that something is wrong with Addevent. I wonder if I can actually list StringBuilder?

Comment: You go to upload a working, minimal, reproducible code example because I'm having a hard time figuring stuff out. Where does 'generatedEvents' come from? But other than that, the only guess I have left is that when you assign 'Date' in 'cevent' you have a different index. You are using 'i' instead of 'n' and but your loop increments 'n'.